# Socket io v3 connection has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have cors error while using Socketio v3
the app is on React backed by Nodejs

## Server Side Codes:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var port = process.env.PORT || '3000'
const io = require("socket.io")(server,{
cors: {
  origin: "*:*",
  methods: ["PUT", "GET", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
  allowedHeaders:["secretHeader"],
  credentials: true
}
})
```

## Client Side Connecting code:

```
const SOCKET_URL = "https://fakeurl.org";
socket.current = io(`${SOCKET_URL}`,{
      secretHeader:{
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
      }
    });
```

***And i got the following error:***

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://fakeurl.org/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NOdqBkN'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Comment: Do you try to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` into allowedHeaders?

Comment: remove `secretHeader` option in client side, and instead of it, use "extraHeaders"

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Socket.io Handling CORS](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/).

```
// server-side
const io = require("socket.io")(server,{
cors: {
  origin: "*",
  methods: ["PUT", "GET", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
  allowedHeaders:["secretHeader"],
  credentials: true
}
})
```

```
// client-side
const SOCKET_URL = "https://fakeurl.org";
socket.current = io(`${SOCKET_URL}`,{
      withCredentials: true,
      extraHeaders: {
          "secretHeader": "secret value"
      }
    });
```

Comment: server is running on an specific port , does it affect the flow?

Comment: it's not a problem. just use `origin: "*"` as a cors option in the server side.

Comment: can i remove ` allowedHeaders:["secretHeader"],` and dont pass any header?

Comment: I believe `origin: "*"` can make the API vulnerable to cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks, and it's not recommended.